# How to print tilde characters correctly with PDFKit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit

When converting HTML to a PDF document characters such as é or ñ are printed as question marks. How can I display them correctly in the PDF document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are setting the encoding on your HTML to UTF-8. It is probably trying to interpret it as US-ASCII

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```